# How do you call a content view function from an instantiated class in Swift?

Tags: swift, function, class, swiftui

Inside my ContentView, I instantiate a class I made called timer. When the timer's "timerText" hits "0:00", I want the timer to call a function in the ContentView to edit the view with information that is not accessible from the timer. However, I don't know how to call a function from the ContentView from inside this timer class. Is this even possible?

If this isn't possible, I could achieve the same goal by making a "timerText" variable in the ContentView that is always synced with the timer object's "timerText" variable. That way, when the ContentView's "timerText" is "0:00", I can just call the function like normal because I'm already "inside" the ContentView. However, I don't know how to have a variable synced together across two different classes. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, this solution will help you:

1. Use `Combine` and make your `timerText` `@Published`;
2. In `ContentView` use `.onReceive` func at any `View` and call your function, if needed.

Here is simple code example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class SpecialTimer: ObservableObject {

    @Published var timerText = "0:01"

    func resetTimer() {
        timerText = "0:00"
    }

}

struct SpecialTimerView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var timer: SpecialTimer
    @State private var didEditedSpecialInfo = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Text(timer.timerText)
                .onReceive(timer.$timerText) { timerText in
                    guard timerText == "0:00" else { return }
                    self.whenTimerResets()
            }

            Button(action: {self.timer.resetTimer()} ) {
                Text("reset timer!")
            }

            Text("timer did reset")
                .opacity(didEditedSpecialInfo ? 1 : 0)

        }

    }

    private func whenTimerResets() {
        print("edit the view with information that is not accessible from the timer")
        didEditedSpecialInfo = true

    }

}

struct SpecialTimerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SpecialTimerView()
            .environmentObject(SpecialTimer())
    }
}
```

Comment: This was what I needed, it worked like a charm Text(timer.timerText)
                .onReceive(timer.$timerText) { timerText in
                    guard timerText == "0:00" else { return }